# Is there a way to force Peacock to use a browser rather than their app on an iPad?

Tags: firefox, ipad

If I watch Peacock in Firefox on MacOS, no commercials are shown. If I watch Peacock using the iPad or Apple TV app! Peacock forces me to watch about 10 ads per show.

When I attempt to watch Peacock on an iPad using Firefox, it forces me to use the app.  I tried asking for the desktop site, but this didn’t resolve the problem.

Are there any tricks to getting peacock to load in a browser on iPadOS?

Comment: Uninstall the app.